# How do you use Fabric to copy files between remote machines?

Tags: python, rsync, fabric

I need to copy huge files from remotemachine1 to remotemachine2-remotemachine10.

What is the best way to do it ? Doing a get on remotemachine1 and then a put to all the remaining machines aren't ideal as the file is huge and I need to be able to send the Fabric command from my laptop. The remotemachines are all in the same network. Or should I do a run('rsync /file_on_remotemachine1 RemoteMachine2:/targetpath/') ?

Is there a better way to do this in Fabric ?

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be running the script from remotemachine1 if you can.